# Convert list of strings into integers with Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to understand Regular Expressions. I have a hard time understanding how I should solve this:

```
import re

fhand = open("assign11.txt")

lst = list()
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall("([\d]+)", line)
    if not len(x) > 0: continue
    numlist = int(x[:])
    d = list.append(numlist)

print(lst)
```

I want to the program to match every substring that is an integer(0-9) with the help of re.findall(), and then convert the substrings it finds into integers, append them to a list, and sum them up.

Put I can´t figure out a way to convert all of the substrings in each line to a integer, it only works if i write int(x[0]), but not if I write (x[:]). How do I change every substring( When there are more than one number in the substring) into a integer?

Comment: Please add the code to your question as text, not as a link to an image.

Comment: `code` not image so that we can copy and edit and figure out the problem

Comment: `numlist = map(int, x)`

Answer (score 2):

Converting a list of strings to a list of integers is done with the `map` function. `map` takes two arguments: the list as well as a function which you wish to apply to each element in the list.

```
map(int, ['1','2'])
> [1,2]
```

An example of your full process:

```
import re
string = "Hello this is number 1,2 and 3. We sum to 6. "
print sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', string)))
>> 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to convert each item in the list to an integer in a new list:

```
list_of_strings = ['1', '11', '123', '-12']
list_of_ints = [int(x) for x in list_of_strings]
>>> list_of_ints
[1, 11, 123, -12]
```

That's the basic idea. Applying that to sum all of the integers in the file:

```
import re

with open("assign11.txt") as fhand:
    numbers = []
    for line in fhand:
        numbers.extend(re.findall("([\d]+)", line))
    print(numbers)
    print(sum(int(x) for x in numbers))
```

This code adds the *items* found by `findall()` to the `numbers` list using `list.extend()`. `list.append()` would add the *list* returned by `re,findall()` which is not what you want. Finally the number strings are converted to ints and the sum calculated.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped!